# How to estimate the confidence of a regression prediction for neural network

Tags: regression, neural-networks, prediction

For a classification task, the output neurons give a continuous output of [0 1], which itself can be treated as confidence, ie, a value closer to 1 means highly confident and closer to 0 means not confident.

Similarly, how do we get the confidence of a regression task prediction?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply train a second network to predict the squared residuals of the first network and use that as a measure of confidence.

Note, that in both, the example in your question and the approach described in this answer, the obtained measure of confidence may not be interpreted as probabilities or confidence intervals. However you could calibrate either measure on a separate test set to obtain an interpretable measure of confidence.